# Implement Fail Whale Page IIS7

Tags: iis-7, load

We are about to launch a website that might end up getting a lot of traction (or none).  I wanted to get some feedback on the best approach to implement a Fail Whale type page should we get nuked and I need to bring up more servers etc.

I was going to do a fail-over load balance to a static page that would show up in the case the main servers are toast, but this that this is to simple an approach.

Any ideas or insight would be appreciated.